# How to have separate Progress Bars for separate TextViews

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I want to have individual progress bars for individual `TextView` that I have. For example, each `TextView` displays some sort of information that I use to query from my database. I can use `AsyncTask` for that, and in `postExecute` I know I can show the `TextView` information that I want to display. However, the issue is, I am making multiple asynchronous calls when the page loads to get different information from my database and I want to display one `ProgressBar` for each of the `TextView` that have information displayed. Is there any way to make a ProgressBar show until the TextView information is available from my database? I am just wondering in terms of UI as I know how to make database calls already.

I Know I can do this with my `AsyncTask`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();  

        //showDialog() here;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //do what you want here//
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //dismissDialog() here;//


    }
```

But then it seems like if i do `showDialog()`, I know I would have to create 4 different `ProgressBar`s in my XML but then how would I ensure that they would only be where my `TextView` lies and not over the entire screen?

Comment: is progress bar beside the textview ok with your project requirement?

Comment: @user1506104 I would want the progress bar to be shown until the information from the database is grabbed. Then I would want to set the visibility of the progress bar to be gone and show the `TextView` where the progress bar was when the information is ready to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can display a progress bar beside each of textview to show the field is still loading the data:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal">

   <TextView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progressbar"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:indeterminate="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Once you have the data ready for one textview, you can call its corresponding `setVisibility(View.GONE)` on the object view. You should call it from your `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your **layout file (activity_main.xml)** may look something like this:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="contents of textview 1" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="contents of textview 2" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your activity,declare the following:

```
ProgressBar progressBar1,progressBar2;
```

and in the **OnCreate()** method of the activity,

```
progressBar1=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar1);
progressBar2=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar2);
```

and finally,in your **onPostExecute()** method, hide the corresponding progressbar:

```
progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or/and,

```
progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```